# how do I connect gorm postgres to grpc golang

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, grpc, grails-orm

I tried to connect gorm postgres to my code (golang language), but when I run it it gives this error:

> ```
> 2023/11/14 07:10:15 C:/Users/Professional/Desktop/проектики
> голанга/filmgrpc/service/DB.go:40 [error] failed to initialize
> database, got error failed to connect to `host=localhost user=user
> database=db`: dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connectex: No
> connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it.)
>
> 2023/11/14 07:10:15 C:/Users/Professional/Desktop/проектики
> голанга/filmgrpc/service/DB.go:41 failed to connect to `host=localhost
> user=user database=db`: dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432:
> connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine
> actively refused it.) [0.515ms] [rows:-] SELECT count(*) FROM
> information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = CURRENT_SCHEMA() AND
> table_name = 'films' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
>
> 2023/11/14 07:10:15 C:/Users/Professional/Desktop/проектики
> голанга/filmgrpc/service/DB.go:41 failed to connect to `host=localhost
> user=user database=db`: dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432:
> connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine
> actively refused it.) [0.518ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE "films" ("id"
> text,"title" text,"genre" text,"created_at" timestamptz,"updated_at"
> timestamptz,PRIMARY KEY ("id")) 2023/11/14 07:10:15 Error connecting
> to the database...failed to connect to `host=localhost user=user
> database=db`: dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connectex: No
> connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it.) exit status 1
> ```

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func init() {
    DatabaseConnection()
}

var DB *gorm.DB
var err error

type Film struct {
    ID        string `gorm:"primarykey"`
    Title     string
    Genre     string
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:false"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:false"`
}

func DatabaseConnection() {
    host := "localhost"
    port := "5432"
    dbname := "db"
    dbuser := "user"
    password := "pass"
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s sslmode=disable",
        host,
        port,
        dbuser,
        dbname,
        password,
    )
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    DB.AutoMigrate(Film{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error connecting to the database...", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Database connection successful...")
}
```

I also thought that I should try it with Docker
(here is the command `docker run -it --name film-frnxx -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_USER=dbuser -e POSTGRES_DB=dbname -e POSTGRES_PORT=port postgres`).

The code itself seems to be correct.

Comment: A network configuration problem.

Comment: how to fix this problem?

Comment: By fixing the network configuration. This is not related to software development.

Comment: You seem to have included a link to an image in place of the error message; can you [edit] the question to include the text of the error?  If you're running some or all of this in Docker, which parts are running in containers, and how are you starting those containers?  (In particular if the application is in a container, the fixed `localhost` name for the database location is probably wrong.)

Comment: I run this not through docker, but with the command: go run .

Answer (score 0):

It  suggests that there is no PostgreSQL server running on the specified host and port, or the server is actively refusing the connection.

1-Check PostgreSQL Server:
Ensure that PostgreSQL is installed on your machine, and the server is running. You can use the following command to start the PostgreSQL server:

```
service postgresql start
```

Make sure to replace service with the appropriate command for your operating system.

2-Check Firewall Settings

3-Check PostgreSQL Authentication:
Ensure that the PostgreSQL server is configured to allow connections from the specified user (dbuser) and that the password is correct. You might need to check the pg_hba.conf file for authentication settings.

4-Use gorm.Open at Runtime:
Consider moving the gorm.Open call from the init function to the main function to ensure the connection attempt occurs when your application is running.